# How to improve MySQL query that already hits INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I optimize a query which already hits Index condition and still take up to 40-80 seconds to process around 400k - 500k records?

```
CREATE TABLE `merchant_bank_transaction ` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`transaction_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`transaction_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`merchant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_primary` (`merchant_id`,`transaction_date`),
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I have a table as above with index:

```
index_primary ('merchant_id', 'transaction_date')
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT id,transaction_date, currency, status
FROM merchant_bank_transaction 
WHERE merchant_id=1
transaction_date>='2020-04-01'
transaction_date<='2020-04-30'
AND transaction_type in ('D', 'W')
ORDER BY id desc, transaction_date desc
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I ran the above query and it took 54 secs++, the explain query is as below:

[image]

Comment: Can you fix your query, please? (I assume some `and` around `transaction_date` and `merchantba0_` has no reference). The problem seems to be that you have too many rows for merchant_id=1, making the index unusable - so how many rows are there for this merchant?

Comment: @Solarflare, woops my bad i fixed it already, estimated to have 400k for this merchant_id = 1, is it normal to take 54 seconds to process 400k records?

Comment: Try adding `transaction_type` as the third column in that index. Having said that, it is the sorting of 400k rows that takes the bigger chunk of time.

Answer (score 0):

In given sample query, condition is based on `merchant_id`, `transaction_date` and `transaction_type`. You are using composite index on `('merchant_id', 'transaction_date')` but there doesn't seems to be an index on `transaction_type` which could cause the query to process each and every record.

You should either modify existing composite index and include `transaction_type` or create a separate index on this single column.

Comment: Since MySQL almost never uses 2 indexes in one SELECT, having such a separate index is unlikely to be used.  (It _could_ happen -- if 'D' and 'W' were very rare types.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
SELECT  id,transaction_date, currency, status
    FROM  merchant_bank_transaction
    WHERE  merchant_id=1
      AND  transaction_date >= '2020-04-01'
      AND  transaction_date  < '2020-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND  transaction_type in ('D', 'W')
    ORDER BY  transaction_date desc, id desc
    LIMIT  0, 50;
```

Changes:

- Adding `AND`
- Including the rest of 4/30 (you included only midnight)
- Flipped the `ORDER BY` columns

The optimal index is one of these.  (The Optimizer will pick between them.)

```
INDEX(merchant_id, transaction_date)
INDEX(merchant_id, transaction_type, transaction_date, id)
INDEX(transaction_date, id)
```

What did you mean by "400k - 500k"?  That is how big the table is?  Or that is how many rows match the `WHERE` clause?

In the latter case, I will provide another approach that will help with the `LIMIT`...

```
SELECT  id,transaction_date, currency, status
    FROM  merchant_bank_transaction
    WHERE  merchant_id=1
      AND  transaction_date >= '2020-04-01'
      AND  transaction_date  < '2020-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND  transaction_type ='D'
    ORDER BY  transaction_date desc, id desc
    LIMIT  0, 50
UNION ALL
SELECT  id,transaction_date, currency, status
    FROM  merchant_bank_transaction
    WHERE  merchant_id=1
      AND  transaction_date >= '2020-04-01'
      AND  transaction_date  < '2020-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND  transaction_type ='W'
    ORDER BY  transaction_date desc, id desc
    LIMIT  0, 50
ORDER BY  transaction_date desc, id desc
LIMIT  0, 50;
```

In this formulation, my second index will be picked for each `SELECT`, then a separate sort will happen for the 100 rows fetched.

I see `OFFSET 0`.  If that might change, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or for how to properly handle the 3 `LIMITs` in the query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id,transaction_date, currency, status
FROM merchant_bank_transaction 
WHERE merchant_id = 1 AND transaction_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-30'AND transaction_type in ('D', 'W')
ORDER BY merchant_bank_transaction.id DESC, merchant_bank_transaction.transaction_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;

Make sure the "order by" columns are indexed for better performance.
```

Comment: Only one index will be used.  It is likely that the Optimizer will pick an index that helps with the `WHERE` and ignore any index that could help with the `ORDER BY`.